# Faster rolling apply std and slope on unevenly-spaced timeseries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a Pandas (1.0.*) dataframe, which contains the record of several physical variables (say Temperature, Pressure and Humidity for example). 
The time space between two record is roughly 1s but varies between 0.8s and 4s.

I want to calculate the standard deviation and the slope (of the linear regression) in a 5-minutes rolling window.

Here is how I do it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
np.random.seed(1)

# Build the dummy dataset for testing
rows, cols = 1000, 3    
datetimes_sec = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=rows, freq='1s').astype(np.int64) / 1e9
shifts = np.random.rand(rows) - 0.5  # Create random shift between -0.5s and +0.5s
datetimes = [sum(x) * 1e9 for x in zip(datetimes_sec, shifts)]    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(rows,cols),
                  columns=['temperature', 'pressure', 'humidity'],
                  index=pd.to_datetime(datetimes))

# Custom function to calculate the slope
def get_slope(series):
    hours_since_epoch = series.index.astype(np.int64) / 3.6e12  # nanosecond to hour, I want the slope to be in [variable's unit] per hour
    slope = np.polyfit(hours_since_epoch, series, 1)[0]
    return slope

# Get the result
df = df.rolling("5min").agg(["std", get_slope])
```

This works, but it is too slow: the last line takes more than 2s for 1000 rows.

I can see that my custom `get_slope` function is responsible, if I replace it by a standard function (e.g. `min()`), it takes 0.007s. But I can find how to make it faster.

If it is not possible to get the same result faster, a workaround solution could be to skip some data lines: do not roll the window on every line (i.e. for 0.8 to 4 second) but do the calculation only every 30s:

- calculate sd and slope of all (~300) data between 00:00:00 and 00:05:00
- calculate sd and slope of all (~300) data between 00:00:30 and 00:05:30
- calculate sd and slope of all (~300) data between 00:01:00 and 00:06:00
- etc.

Instead of:

- calculate sd and slope of all (~300) data between 00:00:00 and 00:05:00
- calculate sd and slope of all (~300) data between 00:00:01 and 00:05:01
- calculate sd and slope of all (~300) data between 00:00:02 and 00:05:02
- etc.

I don't know how to do that (in the proper pandas' way) with unevenly-spaced data.

It would speed up the process by 30, in exchange of a loss of precision.